# Why is there an NaN instead of variable when appending to a bootstrap navbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to be able to dynamically add tabs to a navbar so that the user can create content and then click between the navs to see the different content. As it stands, I have the following:

```js
function view_data_frame(this_data_frame, language){
  $("#html_data_frame_tabs").append('<a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-' +  language + '-' + this_data_frame + '" data-toggle="tab" href="#content-' +
    language + '-' + this_data_frame + '" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-preview" aria-selected="true">hi' +
    + this_data_frame + 'ho</a>');
    beep = "bop";
    $("#html_data_frame_tabs").append('<a>hi' +
    + beep.toString() + 'ho</a>');

}
view_data_frame("name","language");
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav>
  <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="html_data_frame_tabs" role="tablist">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-preview-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#html_preview" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-preview" aria-selected="true">Preview</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

As you can see from the snippet above, when I run the function view_data_frame, it succesfully creates a new tab, and when you inspect the tab properties it actually uses the "this_data_frame" and "language" to dynamically change the attributes of the < a >. However, within the tab html itself for some reason this_data_frame is converted to "NaN".

I'm at a loss at how a line of code that succesfully inputs the variable in parts of it is trying to interpret the variable as a number within the < a > tag?

I've added a variable "beep" within the function to show that this problem occurs even in a much simpler instance of appending an < a > to the div with a dynamic string

Comment: It's a typo. You are repeating your `+` signs to append strings. You have to make a decision, Either END the line with the plus sign or BEGIN the next line with the plus sign not both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would advise to simplify your code by using element creation provided by jQuery:

```js
function addTab(name, lang) {
 debugger;
  let $a = $('<a>', {
   class: 'nav-item nav-link',
    role: 'tab',
    href: '#',
    text: name
  });
  $('.nav-tabs').append($a);
}

addTab('name', 'lang');
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="html_data_frame_tabs" role="tablist">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Preview</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Using such approach will save your debugging time and is much more easy to read and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you have too many `+` signs in your code.

The `+` sign to the left of a number (with no space between) serves as the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) - this is making your code try to convert `beep` into a number, which will obviously result in `NaN` (not a number).

I removed the operator below and I believe now your code works as expected:

```js
function view_data_frame(this_data_frame, language) {
  $("#html_data_frame_tabs").append('<a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-' + language + '-' + this_data_frame + '" data-toggle="tab" href="#content-' +
    language + '-' + this_data_frame + '" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-preview" aria-selected="true">hi' +
    this_data_frame + 'ho</a>');
  beep = "bop";
  $("#html_data_frame_tabs").append('<a class="nav-item nav-link">hi' + beep.toString() + 'ho</a>');

}
view_data_frame("name", "language");
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav>
  <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="html_data_frame_tabs" role="tablist">
    <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-preview-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#html_preview" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-preview" aria-selected="true">Preview</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```